# How to get all opened JSF pages, and close or redirect from server side?

Tags: jsf, iframe, primefaces, liferay, view-scope

We are using Liferay Portal 6.0, and the portlets are Primefaces 3.4, JSF 2.1, We support having more than one browser tab opened for the same user, and each tab can have up to 15 portlets at a time, each portlet is displaying a JSF page (`ViewScopedBean`) using `iframe`.

The problem is that the opened JSF pages (inside a `iframe` inside a portlet) don't know when their portlets get closed or when the whole browser tab gets closed, So they stay in memory until session times out. And this is causing a major problem in server memory leading to complete failure.

My questions are: How can I have the list of opened pages (views) from server side? and how can I also close them? I know that a `ViewScopedBean` gets destroyed when it is redirected to another page (a dummy page as a workaround), so can I redirect each page from the list (If I can have it!) from server side?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Stop looking at the abstractions and start looking at the network protocol. How does the server know what the client is doing? JSF/servlets/portlets are built on HTTP.

Comment: I forgot to say that redirecting the pages with client side Javascript will introduce an annoying OK/Cancel dialogue box at the closing of the browser tab, or window. That's why I am thinking of a server side solution.

Comment: @McDowell What exactly are you suggesting?

Comment: Session time-out problems - session-state vs multiple windows - these problems are inherent in [stateless protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) and there are no easy fixes.

Comment: You may try changing to `@RequestScoped` beans instead.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I can't because we are using Ajax submits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when the whole browser tab gets closed

You can capture a closing tab, with HTML DOM events like [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/beforeunload).

> My questions are: How can I have the list of opened pages (views) from
>   server side?

You can list them in an application scoped bean. i.e : Add a view to a list when the view has been called and initiated, and remove it from the list on tab unload/closure ? From that list you can do lot of checkings.. and even close a session if there are no more views associated with it.

Comment: using Javascript will introduce an annoying dialogue box at the closing of the tab or browser, that's why I am heading for server side. Your second suggestion is really interesting, I will give it a try. Thank you very much.

Comment: _"using Javascript will introduce an annoying dialogue box at the closing of the tab or browser"_ Not necessarily, you can close it silently without prompting a dialog window. If you check inside your `h:body` tag, there is an attribute called `onunload` which will allow you to capture a tab closure event. For the collection of views, you could do something like this , as proposed by JSF guru BalusC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211387/how-to-get-all-the-session-scoped-beans-in-jsf-2. Hope it helps

Comment: Very interesting ideas .. I am trying this Javascript method and see if I can remove the view onunload

Comment: I don't know how can i thank you for this answer .. IT WOOOOOOOOOOOORKED :D :D I was able to redirect the page using The Javascript onunload in the h:body tag, so it subsequently got destroyed, and the annoying dialogue box didn't appear as you said. dude you made my day. thank you very much, that was a very annoying problem for us, and sure our application will be much more stable with this fix. thank again.